# Loop over nested dictionary with duplicate indicies

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I'm trying to set up a nested dictionary *with indicies* and loop a certain command over this nested dictionary.

```
dictionary = {"item 1":{"subitem 1":"one of one","subitem 2":"two of one"},"item 2":{"subitem 1":"one of two", "subitem 2":"two of two"}}
```

The output of the first "round" (or first loop) should be:

```
some.command{input:one of one, output: two of one}
```

The output of the second "round":

```
some.command{input:one of two, output:two of two}
```

and so on. I really want to work with indicies, simply looping through *all* the entries on the second level dictionary won't do (since there are entries the command has to ignore). The loop should look something like this:

```
for x in dictionary.itervalues():
    for y in x.itervalues():
        some.command(input: y["subitem 1], output: y["subitem 2"])
```

This somehow doesn't work, since I cant get access to selected values via the index. If I replace "some.command" with "print y["subitem 1"] I get the error "TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str".

What am I doing wrong? Am I setting up my dictionary up the wrong way or my loop command or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x` is already your nested dictionary; you don't need your inner loop. Rather than use `x` (a rather meaningless name), I used `nested_dict` to clarify what your loop is iterating over:

```
for nested_dict in dictionary.itervalues():
    some.command(input=nested_dict["subitem 1"], output=nested_dict["subitem 2"])
```

Your inner loop then, was looping over the values of that those nested dictionaries; `y` was bound to `"one of one"`, then `"two of one"`, etc. Trying to use `y['some string']` was trying to apply indexing to those strings.

Also, nowhere in these `for` loops is Python using indices. Python `for` loops iterate *directly* over the items. You are telling Python to loop over `dictionary.itervalues()`, so each `nested_dict` is bound to each of the values of `dictionary`. No indices are being used.

Comment: Woah superb, thanks! I lack the reputation to voteup your answer, but I'd definitly do so :-)